# Disable a PHP website temporarily

Tags: php, security, web, iis-6

I have a PHP website that I own. I want to temporarily disable the website while I am making my changes (there are a lot to do). I tried to rename the `index.php` file but the end-user can always navigate to a page by typing the URL ( or if he had bookmarked the page ). Is there a way I can disable the whole website temporarily?

Edit : This accepted answers work for an apache web server. What I am using presently is IIS6 ( and not IIS7 where the same rewrite can be done in web.config file ). Is there a way around for this problem in IIS6?

Comment: This may help http://phpsnips.com/40/Maintenance-Mode

Comment: Delete all files from FTP, Create a password protection over ur whole site for some time. Create 1 file who displays something like "TEMPORARILY OFFLINE!" and include it in all files people can access, or use htaccess rewrite and a lot more...

Comment: Are you insane?? Delete the ftp?

Comment: @ztripez I guess he has everything local, dependent on if hes working with other people or not, he could just delete all files from his FTP server and re-upload when the changes are made. Not sure where your problem is.

Comment: Look into modrewite and do a HTTP 302 status to a temporary page

Comment: Use a rewrite rule http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Redirect-Site-to-Maintenance-Page-using-Apache-and-HTAccess

Comment: @ztripez I can always delete the ftp. But the maintenance work that I am doing involves transaction of huge files. I would realistically want to test in a real web server rather than test it on local machine. The shell rewrite provided a perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.htaccess` file to redirect to maintenance page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

Some useful links:

http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Redirect-Site-to-Maintenance-Page-using-Apache-and-HTAccess

http://perishablepress.com/htaccess-redirect-maintenance-page-site-updates/

http://wp-mix.com/maintenance-mode-htaccess/

Comment: I would add a HTTP 302 for good messure so the indexing don't get messed up.

Comment: And maybe a rewrite condition based on maintener's IP RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000

Answer (score 2):

While `bartek` beat me to an Apache `mod_rewrite` rule that would force the site to redirect all traffic to a maintenance/offline page, I wanted to post my variation on the idea which can allow a specific IP address to access the site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.45.67.890$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^::1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offline.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.great.website/offline.html [R=302,L]
```

Just a note that depending on your version of Apache, you might have to escape the `.` and `:` in the IP addresses like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.890$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^\:\:1$
```

The idea is if the visitor is not coming from the IP address `123.45.67.890`—or the `localhost` addresses of `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `::1` (IPv6)—and the URI requested is not `/offline.html` then redirect that person to `http://your.great.website/offline.html`.

Which means you should just replace `123.45.67.890` with the IP address you would be connecting from to allow you to have a window into the website while you perform work. But anyone else who is not `123.45.67.890`? Well, they see the `offline.html` page.

Answer (score 0):

I would also propose this solution.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !access=dbcaf771cc0c4e23a0fc895d0afa106f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

The idea is unless your request contains `access=dbcaf771cc0c4e23a0fc895d0afa106f` within the query string, you'll simply get redirected to the maintenance page.